# How can I convert a wall to a writing board?

Tags: walls, laminate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which material should I use for a whiteboard that would erase easily?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/which-material-should-i-use-for-a-whiteboard-that-would-erase-easily)

I would like to convert my walls (at least one of them) 
into a laminated surface so I would be able to write things on it. 
Because the wall is massive, and I do need a massive space to write on, 
I'm not sure what kind of a solution there is in order to laminate/coat it 
with a thin layer of writable material (as in, easy to erase and re-write over and over again).

To clarify, I basically want to convert my wall to this

[image]

without finding a huge board.

Comment: you mean like a whiteboard with dry erase pens?

Comment: [This Question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/2194/33) might help, or [This Question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/5392/33), maybe [This Question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/2527/33), or even [This Question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/5760/33).

Comment: Ideapaint seems like the closest thing here, however it's not available in Europe (plus it's quite expensive)

Answer (score 0):

whiteboard paint, quick google search should give you a few options for that:
[Google Search](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?rlz=1C1GPCK_enGB386GB386&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#pq=aluminium%20sheet%20metal&hl=en&cp=11&gs_id=16&xhr=t&q=whiteboard%20paint&pf=p&rlz=1C1GPCK_enGB386GB386&biw=1600&bih=732&sclient=psy-ab&pbx=1&oq=whiteboard%20&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1a63dd651ba9306&ix=seb&ion=1)

another idea is vinyl wrapping the whole wall, but that could cost more than the whiteboard paint - The wife wraps boats in vinyl, and says it would cost about 200 quid to wrap a 7m2 wall and all you would need to do is give it a really good sand.

She also has in the office a white board they made with the vinyl and it's about 5 years old and still going strong :)

Hope that helps.

Martyn

Comment: Edited, got some more info from the wife on vinyl wrapping and it seems like a good way to go, if you could find a local company to you might be able to get it cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to go the chalkboard route: just like there is whiteboard paint, there is chalkboard paint. You just paint it and you have a usable surface for chalk. Some examples:

- [Rustoleum Chalkboard Brush-on](http://www.rustoleum.com/CBGProduct.asp?pid=103)
- [Benjamin Moore Chalkboard Paint](http://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/for-your-home/chalkboard-paint)

My brother has his utility room wall painted in this and it's great. Good for grocery lists, to-do lists, and lots of doodles.

Comment: I live in a rented apartment and the walls are white.. can't go in that direction